# Switch visible div based on user click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hidden

so I have a div with navigational links (set up using ul/li and a href within the li's).

Below that I have 4 other div's. I only want 1 div shown at a time, they will then switch based on the users selection of the navigational LI's

I've used a similar setup on a different page, and have tried to port it over to my current page but to no avail...

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/etakt708/)

Please see the above jsfiddle for the HTML/CSS/JS involved.

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="man-banner"></div>
        <div class="banner-nav" id="tabs">
            <ul class="tabs" style="padding-left: 0px">
                <li class="active"><a href="#wrapper#container#content#tab-content#home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#findvehicle" rel="find_your_vehicle"><span>Find Your Vehicle</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#downloads" rel="downloads"><span>Downloads</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#support" rel="support"><span>Support</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-content">
            <div id="home" class="tab_content">
            1234156124
            </div>
            <div id="findvehicle" class="tab_content">
            abasdjfniasjfnasdf
            </div>
            <div id="downloads" class="tab_content">
            asdfniadhnfiasdn890384834854854jnrjrjr
            </div>
            <div id="support" class="tab_content">
            asdfniadhTHIS IS SUPPORT
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help is welcomed, I am still learning (aren't we always), so with any fixes/tips, please detail why it works, or what i did wrong that's making this not work. (if that makes sense!)

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Your fiddle has a syntax error, which you'll see in the console.  That should probably be addressed before we can help.

Comment: You mean this error?
"An iframe which has both allow-scripts and allow-same-origin for its sandbox attribute can remove its sandboxing."
I haven't used <iframe> in my code?
(sorry if I'm being an idiot.....but I'm a little confused, the jfiddle seems to be working (apart from not hiding the 3 divs)

Comment: No:  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"

Comment: Yup, and just a tip for now; try to use better semantics when coding. Sure you might know what all the a b c d mean and can spot the difference between tab-content and tab_content right now. But others might not, for example down here.

Comment: Yea that code wasn't written by me but it worked in the other page, im not very strong in terms of JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way of achieving it.

HTML - added "navlink" class to your anchor elements, <s>and gave them a data-section attribute that refers to the tab they should show</s>:

```
    <div id="content">
        <div class="banner-nav" id="tabs">
            <ul class="tabs" style="padding-left: 0px">
                <li><a href="#home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#findvehicle" rel="find_your_vehicle"><span>Find Your Vehicle</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#downloads" rel="downloads"><span>Downloads</span></a></li>
                <li><a data-section="support" href="#support" rel="support"><span>Support</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-content">
            <div id="home" class="tab_content">
            1234156124
            </div>
            <div id="findvehicle" class="tab_content">
            abasdjfniasjfnasdf
            </div>
            <div id="downloads" class="tab_content">
            asdfniadhnfiasdn890384834854854jnrjrjr
            </div>
            <div id="support" class="tab_content">
            asdfniadhTHIS IS SUPPORT
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript - see inline comments:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // start of at the home page
  navigateTo("#home");

  // for every navlink element
  $('.tabs > li > a').each(function() {
    //when it is clicked
    $(this).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // navigate to the section ilinked to in the href
      navigateTo($(this).attr('href'));
    });
  });
});

function navigateTo(sectionId) {
  //hide all tabs
  $('.tab_content').hide();

  //then show the one we want
  $(sectionId).show();
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly in Jsfiddle, but when applying to my local files, it's not...

Suggestions on what I should be looking for?

Comment: So, adding <script src="js/MAN-Nav.js" type="text/javascript"> to the html document, results in a blank page with just the background colour.
adding the js into the html using <script></script> works.
Can you help me understand why this is? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you added the man-nav.js script tag before your jQuery one?

Comment: No, but Is it Monday? I acted like it... forgot to close the script after calling it....
All works perfectly, thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: One last question if you don't mind Alex.
When selecting a tab, it moves the scrollbar to put the top of the "content" div at the top of the page, rather than staying at the top - if this makes sense? what do I need to change to stop this from happening?

Comment: That's because of the hrefs in your anchor tags - I've edited which should stop this.

Comment: Ah, I thought it might've been, but my thought process was to add the same href to the top div or something...
Thanks again! I appreciate your time!

Comment: Why not delegate the click to .tabs instead of applying it to each .navlink?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need separate click handlers for each menu item. The `#tabs li` click handler will suffice. I removed the click handlers on each of the links since they are not necessary.

```js
$("#tabs li").click(function() {
  //  First remove class "active" from currently active tab
  $("#tabs li").removeClass('active selected');

  //  Now add class "active" to the selected/clicked tab
  $(this).addClass("active selected");

  //  Hide all tab content
  $(".tab_content").hide();

  //  Here we get the href value of the selected tab
  var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

  //  Show the selected tab content
  $(selected_tab).fadeIn(0);

  //  At the end, we add return false so that the click on the link is not executed
  return false;
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.man-banner {
  background: url("../images/man-logo.png") no-repeat top;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  height: 93px;
  max-width: 915px;
  margin: 15px 15px 0 15px;
}
.banner-nav {
  background: #F0F1F2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D6D8DB;
  height: 40px;
  max-width: 915px;
  margin: 0 15px 15px;
}
.banner-nav a {
  font-family: MAN-light, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  color: #303C49;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.banner-nav a:hover {
  color: #303C49;
}
.banner-nav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 5;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.banner-nav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
ul.tabs li.selected a,
ul.tabs li.selected a:hover {
  top: 0px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: #FFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  color: #000;
}
/***************************/

/**  Main Content Area  **/

/***************************/

#content {
  width: 950px;
  margin: 5 10;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div class="man-banner"></div>
  <div class="banner-nav" id="tabs">
    <ul class="tabs" style="padding-left: 0px">
      <li class="active"><a data-tab-id="#home"><span>Home</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#findvehicle" rel="find_your_vehicle"><span>Find Your Vehicle</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#downloads" rel="downloads"><span>Downloads</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#support" rel="support"><span>Support</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab_content">
      1234156124
    </div>
    <div id="findvehicle" class="tab_content">
      abasdjfniasjfnasdf
    </div>
    <div id="downloads" class="tab_content">
      asdfniadhnfiasdn890384834854854jnrjrjr
    </div>
    <div id="support" class="tab_content">
      asdfniadhTHIS IS SUPPORT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use css to show and hide the blocks when there is an onclick event.

Here some sample code:

**CSS**

```
.activetab {
    display: block;
}

.tab {
    display: none;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT / JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabmenu").on("click", function() {
        $(".activetab").removeClass("activetab");
        $(this).addClass("activetab");
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="man-banner"></div>
    <div class="banner-nav" id="tabs">
        <ul class="tabs" style="padding-left: 0px">
            <li class="active tabmenu"><a href="#wrapper#container#content#tab-content#home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li class="tabmenu"><a href="#findvehicle" rel="find_your_vehicle"><span>Find Your Vehicle</span></a></li>
            <li class="tabmenu"><a href="#downloads" rel="downloads"><span>Downloads</span></a></li>
            <li class="tabmenu"><a href="#support" rel="support"><span>Support</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab_content tab">
        1234156124
        </div>
        <div id="findvehicle" class="tab_content tab">
        abasdjfniasjfnasdf
        </div>
        <div id="downloads" class="tab_content tab">
        asdfniadhnfiasdn890384834854854jnrjrjr
        </div>
        <div id="support" class="tab_content tab">
        asdfniadhTHIS IS SUPPORT
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want I can create a JSFiddle to see how it works

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, you are closing your document ready callback more than once.

```
$("#findvehicle").click(function(){
        $('a[rel="find_your_vehicle"]').trigger("click");
    });
}); // Remove this

    $("#downloads").click(function(){
        $('a[rel="downloads"]').trigger("click");
    });
}); // Remove this
```

When you remove these extra closes the tabs appear. You'll probably want to hide all but the default tab in that document ready call also.